# bash script - 2 variables in loop

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I have a file ip_details.txt with following;

```
Peer "ATBBB010.domain.com:1111;transport=tcp" ConnectAddress="10.184.88.29,10.184.88.30" LocalPort="0"
Peer "ATBBB020.domain.com:1111;transport=tcp" ConnectAddress="10.184.88.61,10.184.88.62" LocalPort="0"
Peer "CHBBB010.domain.com:1111;transport=tcp" ConnectAddress="10.161.144.5,10.161.144.6" LocalPort="0"
Peer "CHBBB020.domain.com:1111;transport=tcp" ConnectAddress="10.161.144.21,10.161.144.22" LocalPort="0"
Peer "DABBB010.domain.com:1111;transport=tcp" ConnectAddress="10.160.130.5,10.160.130.6" LocalPort="0"
Peer "DABBB020.domain.com:1111;transport=tcp" ConnectAddress="10.160.130.21,10.160.130.22" LocalPort="0"
Peer "ATCCC010.domain.com:1111;transport=tcp" ConnectAddress="10.199.88.29,10.199.88.30" LocalPort="0"
Peer "ATCCC020.domain.com:1111;transport=tcp" ConnectAddress="10.199.88.61,10.199.88.62" LocalPort="0"
Peer "CHCCC010.domain.com:1111;transport=tcp" ConnectAddress="10.161.155.5,10.161.155.6" LocalPort="0"
Peer "CHCCC020.domain.com:1111;transport=tcp" ConnectAddress="10.161.155.21,10.161.155.22" LocalPort="0"
Peer "DACCC010.domain.com:1111;transport=tcp" ConnectAddress="10.199.130.5,10.199.130.6" LocalPort="0"
Peer "DACCC020.domain.com:1111;transport=tcp" ConnectAddress="10.199.130.21,10.199.130.22" LocalPort="0"
```

I currently use these 2 scripts/commands to ping the IP Addresses of the specific type nodes.

To Ping the BBB nodes first IP (IP before the comma delimiter);

```
for i in `cat ip_details.txt | grep BBB | awk '{print $3}' | cut -d= -f2 | cut -d, -f1 | tr -d '[="=]'`; do ping -I eth0 -c 3 $i >> /dev/null ; [ $? != 0 ] && echo $i || echo "Ping to $i Good"; done
```

To Ping the BBB nodes 2nd IP (IP after the comma delimiter);

```
for i in `cat ip_details.txt | grep BBB | awk '{print $3}' | cut -d= -f2 | cut -d, -f2 | tr -d '[="=]'`; do ping -I eth0 -c 3 $i >> /dev/null ; [ $? != 0 ] && echo $i || echo "Ping to $i Good"; done
```

I get the as the following;

```
Ping to 10.184.88.29 Good
Ping to 10.184.88.61 Good
.
.
```

Similarly I grep CCC for CCC Nodes.

**I need a script to ping these IP Addresses per nodes types or both types together and get output like this;**

```
Ping from <hostname> to ATBBB010 IP1 <ip address> is Good
....
....
....

Ping from <hostname> to ATBBB010 IP2 <ip address> is Good 
....
....
....
```

If the ping fails;

```
Ping from <hostname> to ATBBB010 IP1 <ip address> failed
.....
.....

Ping from <hostname> to ATBBB010 IP2 <ip address> failed
.....
.....
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

msgPrefix="Ping from $HOSTNAME to"
prevNode=
while read node ip; do
  [[ "$node" == "$prevNode" ]] || i=1
  ping -I eth0 -c 3 "$ip" >/dev/null && status='is good' || status='failed'
  echo "$msgPrefix $node IP$i $ip $status"
  ((++i)); prevNode=$node
done < <(awk -F'"|\\.domain\\.com|,' '{ print $2, $5 }' ip_details.txt)
```

Comment: it did not work. I get `code`[root@Linux1 temp]# ./testPing 
awk: warning: escape sequence `\.' treated as plain `.'
Usage: ping [-LRUbdfnqrvVaA] [-c count] [-i interval] [-w deadline]
            [-p pattern] [-s packetsize] [-t ttl] [-I interface or address]
            [-M mtu discovery hint] [-S sndbuf]
            [ -T timestamp option ] [ -Q tos ] [hop1 ...] destination
Ping from Linux1 to ATBBB010 IP1 10.184.88.29 failed
Usage: ping [-LRUbdfnqrvVaA] [-c count] [-i interval] [-w deadline]
            [-p pattern] [-s packetsize] [-t ttl] [-I interface or address]'`code`

Comment: Re `awk` warning: double the `\ ` instances in the `-F` option-argument, as I've just done in my update.

Comment: Re  `ping` failure: I simply forgot the IP address operand: append `<space>"$ip"`, as I've just done in my update.